# SQL - Best practice for One-to-Many with Multiple "One" Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, django-models

My scenario is difficult too explain in just a short title, so here's an example:

I have multiple tables "birthday_event", "meeting_event", "dinner_event" and they have multiple children in a table called "attendees". Essentially, I have 3 distinct One-to-Many relationships: "birthday_event" has many "attendees", "meeting_event" has many "attendees", and so on.

Each of the "event" tables have their own specific attributes. Normally, I would have a foreign key "event_id" in "attendees" so the relationship is robust, but there are many different event tables that can fulfill the "event_id" attribute, so it won't be a strict foreign key, if that makes sense.

My understanding is that when a foreign key is established, it is strongly linked to an attribute in a single table, not multiple tables like the 3 event tables in the example. It is also my understanding that foreign keys should not ever be null so as to ensure robustness of data. So, what is the best practice for establishing a robust relationship between my many events and many attendees?

My possible solutions:

- Use "event_id" as a normal attribute in the "attendees" table so that all three events can use "attendees". The drawback is that this is only a pseudo-foreign key.
- Create 3 different "attendee" tables for each event, so there would be "birthday_attendee", "meeting_attendee", and "dinner_attendee" tables. The drawback is more tables.
- Using a junction table like "event_attendee" doesn't work because then this table will also have a problem with linking a single foreign key "event_id" to multiple event tables.

Which of these or other solutions is ideal for making the database design understandable, scalable, and high-performance?

By the way, I am planning to conduct model operations on these database tables using a Django backend, if that has any affect on the answer.

Comment: This is a faq, google re database/sql subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism. The multiple FKs design is an anti-pattern. You would find this if you actually tried to google, as you always should, many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: That duplicate relates to MSSQL and does not take into consideration the functionality available in MSSQL not available in PostgreSQL and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a solution for you, with table inheritance.  It is well described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html).

Basically, you can have an `events` table and then have three different types of events.  You can have a foreign key reference to either the specific events or to the parent `events` table.

For instance, you can have a generic `eventAttendees` table.  This would have a foreign key to `events`.  But the reference could be to any of the specific event types.  The specific event types would then have the common columns from `event` (perhaps only `eventId`) and only the columns for that specific type.

Comment: greatest invent ever after row_number().

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I guess the pattern I was looking for was inheritance. I'll attempt to solve this using Django model inheritance and postgresql. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a slight design problem, so I'll address that first before I go on to your question in the current context.

Can an `event` be more than one of the following: birthday, meeting, dinner? If not, then the `event` table should have en `event_type` column which determines which event type it is. The `event` table should then hold all columns that are common across all events. For extra columns, you can have the birthday_event, meeting_event, and dinner_event tables, that 0/1-1 with the event table.

So what is this 0/1-1? A one-to-one relationship where one side is nullable. So yes, it is fine for a foreign key to be nullable. A nullable foreign key just means that there may or may not be a relationship, but that relationship *must* be against the table that is foreign key constrained to.

Since you have tagged this as PostgreSQL, I will offer another alternative - one `event` table with the `event_type` column, and an `event_details` column of type `jsonb`. This is a relatively new PostgreSQL type that allows you to store JSON data in a field, and then interrogate that column like it's a deeply nested array of columns. (See [PostgreSQL documentation on the json/jsonb types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html))

---

I would say that no matter if you have a central event table with all the common information, or if you farm the information out to the three satellite tables, you still want to go with an `event_attendees` table to store the attendees. Attendees relate to an event, they are not concerned with an event type.